# Maintaining enough resources?

Tags: banished

I've been playing the past few days, and I have most of the basics down fairly well. I'm maintaining 50-100 residents no problem, so that's a good step up from a few days ago. However I'm always *barely* maintaining my resource count.

What I mean is that my current town of ~45 residents is running off 3 forrester's lodges each staffed full, and only then am I able to maintain a positive supply of logs and firewood. Constructing any new buildings essentially wastes my firewood supply to 0 for a season or two until I have spare logs for firewood (and I'm only talking about 50-100 logs for additional buildings in a given year). Does this seem normal, or am I mis-managing something?

I'm also concerned with maintaining iron and stone. Both my current town and the previous one I've mined up all surface stone/iron that I could within reasonable distance of my town. I don't want to build quarries because that land can never be used from then on. I've gone about 15 years on my previous town and 10 years on this one, and not once have I seen stone or iron offered through trading. Again, what would be the better strategy in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the forester lodges, how far are the foresters walking?  Do they have houses to live in near the lodges?  Do they have stockpiles to drop their wood off at near the lodges?  How far do they have to go for food, tools, coats, and herbs when they have a need for those things?  Walking can take a lot of time.  I've seen students with a large walk time to the school graduate in twice the time of closer students.

Are the lodges overlapping each other or covering lots of area where wood can't grow?  There needs to be physical trees within the radius and they need to be not contending with each other.

A full staff of 3 lodges would be 12 foresters, right?  That should be overkill.  Don't forget to check that they've all got both cut and plant activities active.

Regarding trading for iron and stone, here's a couple of tips.

First, remember to go into the last tab of the trade station window and specify iron and stone as requests, and make sure to set the drop-down to "every time".  To maximize the chances, remove other requests.

Second, more trade stations = more trade.  I don't expand very fast so I don't know how many trade stations you'd need to support fast growth, but I do know that in my flagship town I have three and am considering building more.

Third, clicking dismiss when you've traded for all you want, to get the trader to leave sooner,  might get a new trader sooner.  I haven't kept track.

Fourth, remember to have multiple commodities to trade.  Some traders are only interested in some things.

Fifth, consider one quarry with one worker.  Having a slow trickle of stone can help with minor shortages, and the quarry will last a long, long time under that load.

Comment: I have a main road leading south. Both forrester lodges are on either side of the road, so that the yellow circle are 1 tile from the road itself non-overlapping. There are 4 houses on this road where the forresters and hunters are assigned to, and they are amply stocked with food. There is also a stock pile near the homes as well.

Comment: Also I can't seem to place orders unless with a specific trader, and even then said trader only offers certain goods to order?

Comment: Yeah, clearly, you must have a problem here. I'm runing a city of 300+ citizens with 3 forester lounges.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider is if you have a market distributing goods. With the Market your people will only take what they need instead of scooping up as much as they can carry so it's much more efficient then living out of Stock Piles and Store Houses.

If it is lack of a Market that's holding you back, make sure that when you build it get all of your houses(or as many as possible) within the radius. Don't worry about your Store Houses or Stock Piles being inside, it's the houses that matter here.

Make sure your caps are at reasonable levels as well. Don't let your Black Smith waste all your lumber on Tools when you already have a reasonable supply, at my ~175 pop town right now my caps for Firewood, Tools and Clothes are ~400, 50 and 50 respectively and I'm maintaining fine. I could actually drop my Firewood cap lower but I like to over produce because I use it to trade as well.

In regards to 3 Forester clusters at max workers. I have that as well and I'm supplying my ~175 pop fine with them and I didn't put houses near them. I know it would improve their efficiency, I just never did it. Just make sure they have a reletively close stock pile to dump into. Make sure there is no other debris in their radius and place them in such a way as to minimize tree loss. As Quillbreaker said, they can't plant on hills or water so that is all wasted and will hurt your harvest.

Trading is kind of up to the RNG Gods as to what trader you get from what I can tell. I haven't noticed any patterns in which trader shows up or what they have. The only thing I can say here is that when you put in a request for an order make sure to change the drop down menu in that same tab from NEVER to either JUST THIS ONCE or ALWAYS. Otherwise that trader will never fill your order.

Once you've stabalized your resources, firewood, tools and clothes are the best things to trade. Trading completed goods for raw materials is probably the most efficient way to go